# How to share HTTP2/gRPC streams between server instances?

Tags: go, microservices, grpc, http2

I'm writing a simple chat app using a gRPC server implemented in Go.

When a user connects, the function CreateStream is called. This functions saves the stream in a Connection list:

```
type Server struct {
    Connection []*Connection
}

func (s *Server) CreateStream(pconn *proto.Connect, stream proto.Broadcast_CreateStreamServer) error {
    conn := &Connection{
        stream: stream,
        id:     pconn.User.Id,
        active: true,
        error:  make(chan error),
    }

    s.Connection = append(s.Connection, conn)

    return <-conn.error
}
```

Broadcasting a message is done by looping through the connections and pushing a message using `stream.Send`.

This works great in a simple monolith setup.

Things quickly gets more complicated when the microservice is located behind a load balancer, since new instances of the server can be created and destroyed.

**Question:** How to manage http/2 (or gRPC) streams in a microservice environment?

Is it possible to save the stream in a database? This would allow multiple instances of the same microserver to have access to the same streams.

Answer (score 0):

So you can use some kind of message queues like Kafka or RabbitMQ to store the message protobuf that one client is trying to broadcast with a message type say `BROADCAST_ALL`. The consumer can then pick up the broadcast task and push it across all the receiver via RPC using the protobuf that was saved.

In fact the message queues are nothing different than golang channels. Go channels are also queue/works like queue.